# Windows 7 Task Scheduler advanced settings unclear

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a task that runs once an hour. The functions in the "Edit Trigger" dialog are unclear and seem to conflict. Under settings, the finest time interval for recurrence is "daily", with "recur every 1 days".

Under Advanced Settings, I can set it to repeat task every 1 hour, but the duration is unclear. Is the proper duration 1 day, since the task itself is repeated daily? I.E. the task runs once a day, but then the advanced setting causes it to repeat hourly for 1 day.

My initial attempt to set Daily, and repeat every hour for a duration of one day only ran once (as far as I can tell).

Do I need do set the duration to "indefinitely"? If the advanced setting is "indefinitely", then should the base setting be "one time" to prevent the advanced setting repetition from overlapping and duplicating the base setting of daily recurrence?

Is there any web resource that clearly defines the meaning of these settings and describes how the basic settings interact with the advance settings?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hopefully this will help. I do something similar to run a batch hourly that makes copies of certain files.

---

[image]

I wanted to add that there are actually several ways to get the same result. I could have set the task to run Daily and repeat hourly for a duration of one day. I happen to prefer the way I've illustrated (it seems clearer to me). Also, it's worth mentioning that the values in most of the drop-downs are not fixed. You could set it repeat every 2 hours, or 4 minutes; pretty much whatever you type in, it'll take.

Comment: Thank you Bill for this comment. It helped me confirm what I had already guessed without too much trial and error.

Comment: It's useful to note that there is an option `Run task as soon as possible after scheduled start is missed` on the **Settings** tab which will take care of the case of if the machine was powered down and so the task didn't run so won't repeat.